# Can't acces a class because of a nameError in a undefined (event) attribute in __init__() of which I don't know how to define it! (Python)

Tags: python, events, tkinter, bind, nameerror

I am getting this error :

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "D:\Mario\modules\MovingBackground_4.py", line 54, in bg =
> BackgroundImage(canvas, event) NameError: name 'event' is not defined.

I am new to Python and reading a lot now about every aspect of the Python language and the logic behind it, but I am not familiair with the specific argument 'event', yet and most errors. After a print(event)-test I found out it stores positions, keynumbers, etc,. I don't know how to define it (beforehand?) so I can pass it down to bg = BackgroundImage(canvas, event) . Anyone?

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk

import time
import keyboard
import random



posOfBackgrImage_X = 500
posOfBackgrImage_Y = -40




tk = Tk()    
canvas = Canvas (tk, width = 256, height = 224 ) 
canvas.pack()
tk.update()


class BackgroundImage:
    
    def __init__(self, canvas, event):

        self.canvas = canvas
        #self.event = event
        self.background = PhotoImage(file = "d:\Mario\images\Backgrounds\smw-bg-clouds1.png") #loads a background image and makes an instance of that
        self.marioBackGround = self.canvas.create_image(posOfBackgrImage_X, posOfBackgrImage_Y , image=self.background, anchor=NE) #loads in the parameters the height, witth and the object 'filename'.
        self.x = 0
        self.canvas_width = self.canvas.winfo_width()
        
   
    def move(self):

        if event.char == "a":
            self.canvas.move(self.marioBackGround, -10, 0)
        elif event.char == "d":
            self.canvas.move(self.marioBackGround, 10, 0)

    tk.bind("<Key>", move)

    
    def draw(self):
     
        self.canvas.move(self.marioBackGround, self.x, 0)
        pos = self.canvas.coords(self.marioBackGround)
        #canvas.pack()

    

    
bg = BackgroundImage(canvas, event)
#g.GameLoop()


while 1:
    bg.move()   
    bg.draw()
    tk.update_idletasks()
    tk.update()
    time.sleep(0.01)
```

Comment: I don’t think you need event for your constructor. Remove it and see what happens.

Comment: You have defined your class to require an event when you create an instance, and you aren't passing the event. Your class doesn't use the event, so why are you requiring it? Is this your code, or did you copy it from someone else?

Comment: befor `bg = BackgroundImage(canvas, event)` you have to create `event = ...` Or remove this `event` from definition and execution because you don't use this `event` inside class.

Comment: tk.bind() shoud be inside `__init__` and it should use `self.move()` instead of `move()`. `Bind` will send extra information about event and function `move()` has to get it `def move(self, event)`. I don't know why in loop you runs the same function `bg.move()`  - and if you want to execute it then you have to execute with event information because you need it in `def move(self, event):` Shortly: you have many small mistakes and you have to learn basis about tkinter and Object Oriented Programming (OOP) which means classes.